# Help ! How to remove the disk out of software raid

Tags: raid, disk

I'm really new to Linux and I bought a dedicated server recently and I have uploaded many images there.

But today, I found that the server was actually configured with 4×4 TB software RAID which is overkill,

The question is how do I opt out of the SDC and SDD or any other ways to get more available disk space

[image]

Edit:

`cat /proc/mdstat`:

[image: cat /proc/mdstat]

I want to keep the maximum two disks for one raid. That way I'll have more storage for data/images.

So it would be great If I can make two RAIDs with 2×4 TB.

Comment: What do you mean "overkill"?  What type of RAID are you trying to achieve?  Do you just want size without redundancy (which is very dangerous when it comes to file storage)?  What type of RAID is it already configured as?  Please add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` to your question.  Also add more detail of what you want.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Terrance, Thank you and can you please check my updated question

Comment: I got an answer from the support guy from server provider and he said I have to backup the data to get the system re-install otherwise no way to fulfill my request

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using in this server?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: One other command to run to see how this RAID 1 is configured.  `awk '/: active/ {print $1}' /proc/mdstat | while read drv; do sudo mdadm -D /dev/$drv; done`  Please copy and paste the output to your question.  But you might be looking at a complete rebuild into 2 separate arrays which would require you to backup your data before they do it.  Also, you do understand that if they do a 2xRAID 1 you will have a maximum of 4T total.

Comment: Thank you I think i need to backup the data.

Comment: There's 350g images and I don't how to make compression faster . Will it faster to Rsync after compress the director or direct sync to Other server